# GeoServer SLD env function does not work

Tags: geoserver, sld, function, environment-variable, getmap

I have a database: [image: database]

and I made with it a GeoServer getMap request which works great for one year (one column).
[image]
But I want to change the year programmatically with JavaScript (I am open for better ideas). For that I found the "env" function in SLD: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/substitution.html But the following code does not work:

```
<Rule>
       ...
        <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
          <ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Function name="env">
              <ogc:Literal>years</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>yr1995</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
          </ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
       ...
     </Rule>
```

In the PropertyName-Tag I am writing the column name. If I only would write this:

```
<ogc:PropertyName>yr1995</ogc:PropertyName>
```

then all the data are properly displayed in the map. But I want, that in the URL I can pass a year with ...&env=years:yr2015... as in in the documentation written. So my goal is that I pass a year as parameter in the URL and in SLD I take the column which is passed with the URL. So what am I doing wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 2):

A PropertyName can only contain a fixed string, it cannot work with an expression inside (by OGC filter specification).

What you are trying to do can be achieved using a dedicated filter function, called "property", which allows for dynamic property lookups.
Something like this should work (but did not test it, mind):

```xml
         <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
          <ogc:Function name="property">
            <ogc:Function name="env">
              <ogc:Literal>years</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>yr1995</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
          </ogc:Function>
          <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
```